# how to read and parse resource xml file in android

Tags: xml, parsing

I have stored my xml file under res/xml/project.xml

how to read,parse and display xml file

Thank You`

my xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?<AllProjects><project> <title>test</title <author>Peter</author> <publication-Date>2005</publication-Date> <price>29.99</price</project> <project > <title>android</title><author>Ray</author>
<publication-Date>2003</publication-Date><price>39.95</price> </project></AllProjects>
```

Comment: it's an android application with eclipse IDE

Answer (score 2):

There's a good step-by-step guide for doing this on Android [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/11/boost-android-xml-parsing-xml-pull.html) using the XmlPullParser.